# jumping to a id tag with ui-router

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-sref to go between states, but I want to create a jumping state that goes directly to a id tag.

Eg. I have 'home' state and in that state a have a section with a tag, for instance singForm, I want to have another state for example 'blog' state that have a ui-sref that links to state 'home' but it should scroll (redirect, jump, scroll however you wanna called) to the mentioned singForm,

any help will be more than appreciate it.

Comment: are you talking about jumping to a specific place on the same page?

Comment: yes I am, sorry if is too silly question just that I don't figure out how to do it with ui-router

Comment: so do you press a button on the page or a link? because it can be pretty easy to do directly in the html, I dont think you even need any angular code to move around a html page.

Comment: well the situation is the following, the all page is created with ui-router and this bottom is part of the header (that is common to all pages (it's a template)) the bottom should jump to a section in a page (state) if is on this state or jump to this state directly to the section if in other page, it is not possible to put directly the href in the <a> tag as will think the router is wrong address for the state and will send to error state